# for loop to multiply index 0 with 1, index 1 with 2, index 2 with 3

Tags: javascript, arrays

how could i generate a loop that iterates through a array, and its just multiplying the next index?

example:

array= [0,1,2,3,4,5]

```
0x1
1x2
2x3
3x4
4x5
```

i know that i need to have a nested loop, but I cannot find the solution.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < Positions.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < Positions.length; j++) {
    
      
      console.log(Positions[i].number * Positions[j].number  )  
 
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: Please try: `console.log([0,1,2,3,4,5].map((n, i, arr) => (i > 0 ? n * arr[i-1] : undefined)).filter(Number));` and share feedback, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current implementation is that you are looping over every index twice: once for the outer loop and once for the inner loop. To get the item at the index after `i` you can simply write `Positions[i + 1].number`.

You should loop over every index once like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < Positions.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(Positions[i] * Positions[i + 1])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arrayValues = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arrayValues.forEach((value, index) => {
  if (index !== (arrayValues.length - 1)) {
    console.log(`${value} * ${index + 1}  = ${value * (index + 1)}`)
  }
})
```